# Error Type mismatch error in Akka scaladsl in Akka-Http code

Tags: scala, akka, future, akka-http

Im new to Akka framework and i get the below error message when im trying to run my code.

The method which is called through the api code returns a
`Future[List[HashMap[String,Object]]]`

The api code(akka-http route) which calls this method:

```
@GET
  @Path("getList/{name}")
  @Authorization("basicAuth")
  @Operation(summary = "Get list", description = "Returns a list",
    parameters = Array(new Parameter(name = "name", in = ParameterIn.PATH, description = "name", required=true)),
    security = Array(new SecurityRequirement(name="basicAuth")),
  )
    def getList: Route = {
      path("getList" / Segment) { name =>
        get {
          complete(getListService(name))
        }
      }
    }
```

I get the below error message

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[List[scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[String,Object]]]
 required: akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
          complete(getList(param))
```

returning a future should not be giving this error, i'm a bit confused as im not able to pinpoint where the mistake is.
Any suggestions would greatly help.Kindly let me know if any more info is required.

Comment: maybe the problem is in the value of your hashmap. Note that the compiler is searching a json marshaller for a specific type. If you have a java.lang.Object it does not know how to serialize it. Try to change the Object to String, just for testing.

Comment: It requires an entity that it can serialize to json. `HashMap[String, Object]` isn't something that akka is able to serialize out of the box. You have to either change the return type to something other than `Object` or define a custom marshaller. I doubt that you need an `Object` serializer, you probably want to have some class here instead. Here you have examples of serialization using spray: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/json-support.html.

Comment: @Ava Please post this answer as an answer so that it is clear that this question has been answered. It doesn't matter if you don't have a full solution, this is enough to point people to the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks @Ava! i guess i need to define a class instead of object, i'll try that out and post if it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires an entity that it can serialize to JSON. `HashMap[String, Object]` isn't something that Akka is able to serialize out of the box. You have to either change the return type to something other than `Object` or define a custom marshaller. I doubt that you need an `Object` serializer, you probably want to have some class here instead. Here you have examples of serialization using spray: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/json-support.html

Comment: Yes this seems to work for me. I created a custom class and it doesn't give the error anymore Thanks!